# Вывод массива в виде пирамиды

Tags: c++, массивы, вывод

Есть одномерный массив `array` и его размер `array_size`.

Код, выводящий массив в виде треугольника:

```
int i = 0;
for (int j = 1; true; ++j) {
    for (int k = 0; k < j; ++k) {
        cout << '\t' << array[i];
        ++i;

        if (i == array_size) {
            cout << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    cout << std::endl;
}
```

[image: Вывод]

Как его изменить, чтобы массив выводился в форме пирамиды?

Comment: А как именно? 1, 2, 3 элемента в строке или 1,3,5? Есть гарантии, что `array_size` такой, что позволяет получить пирамиду?

Comment: @Harry, В первой строке один элемент, в каждой следующей на 1 больше. Как на картинке, только чтобы получилось центрированно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то типа

```
void out(int* a, int N, int w = 5)
{
    int m = ceil((sqrt(1+8*N)-1)/2);
    for(int n = 0, row = 1;n < N;++row)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < (m-row)*w/2; ++i) cout << " ";
        for(int i = 0; i < row && n < N; ++i) cout << setw(w) << left << a[n++];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

С выравниванием в пределах поля поиграйтесь сами...

Вот как это примерно выглядит - https://ideone.com/qDargx